# A hexagon with side 2 which contains 20 points there are at least 2 with a distance less than 1

Tags: discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

question:
in a hexagon with side 2 there are not more than 19 points with the minimum distance of 1.

I can prove this for 24 points. they make $8\times3=24$ regions so with 25 points there's at least 1 with a point inside.